# debug backbone app error: Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

This is my first day of learning backbone.  I have been going through some tutorials to get a better grasp.  I keep getting the same error

```
Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined
```

I have come across this with a couple of tutorials I've tried.

I made sure to load backbone local storage last.

This error keeps happening when I try to do a fetch in backbone.

For now my code is very short

```
var Beer = Backbone.Model.extend();

var BeerList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Beer
});

var BeerList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Beer,
   url: 'http://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer'
});
var beers = new BeerList();
beers.fetch();
beers.bind('reset',function() {
    console.log(beers);
}).
```

I have also tried to change the url to a json file, but I keep getting the same problem.  I am wondering how to debug this issue?